# Multiple hooks per nftables chain?

Tags: iptables, nftables

Is it possible to define multiple hooks in nftables chain or is there any other elegant way how to prevent duplicationg the rules inside (without include from another file)?

```
table inet raw {
    chain mangle {
        type filter hook { prerouting, input, output, forward } priority -190; policy accept;

        ct state invalid counter drop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a base chain has only one hook into netfilter.

But within the same table, you can call the same *user* chain from each base chain. Here's an example, with extra counters showing their state after a single `ping -c1 127.0.0.1`:

```
table inet myfilter {
    chain mypreroutingchain {
        type filter hook prerouting priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 2 bytes 168
        jump myuserchain
    }

    chain myinput {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 2 bytes 168
        jump myuserchain
    }

    chain myforward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0
        jump myuserchain
    }

    chain myoutput {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 2 bytes 168
        jump myuserchain
    }

    chain mypostrouting {
        type filter hook postrouting priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 2 bytes 168
        jump myuserchain
    }

    chain myuserchain {
        oif "lo" counter packets 4 bytes 336
        iif "lo" counter packets 4 bytes 336
        counter packets 8 bytes 672
        ct state invalid counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
    }
}
```

the same user chain *myuserchain* was called 8 times for the ping:

outgoing *echo-request*: from *output*+*postrouting*, incoming echo request from *prerouting*+*input*, then again the same with *echo-reply*.